# Highcharts Windbarb with ajax data loading

Tags: javascript, ajax, highcharts

OK. Rephrasing an unanswered earlier question.

I have a chart as shown below with the data loading dynamically through ajax.
A simplified version (without ajax) of this graph works fine as shown in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HansR/ce95g2ka/28/).

The code below is the chart as I use it, straight from its context.

[image]

The idea is there are several timeseries (x-axis) in the graph and I wish to display the wind characteristics of speed and direction at those same times through windbarbs. The windbarbs take two arguments at each defined x-value all other series take one argument (the y-axis).

1. My question is: why doesn't it work (why the stackdump) while it does work in jsfiddle (without the ajax call and thus without the addSeries call?
2. As a derivative: in the jsfiddle the onSeries attribute does  not work. What is wrong there?
3. And finally: is it possible to get the windbarbs above the series graphs and not fixed on the x-axis?

The problem seems to be in the loading of the wind data after the loading of the other series. As that part is in the ajax call with the (idx == 'wind') condition it is quite easy to spot. It breaks in the setData call of highStock with the following stackdump:

```
Uncaught TypeError: r is undefined
setData highstock.src.js:33902
init highstock.src.js:33182
init highstock.src.js:54816
init windbarb.src.js:361
initSeries highstock.src.js:27886
addSeries highstock.src.js:36888
fireEvent highstock.src.js:2112
addSeries highstock.src.js:36887
success line 2 > injectedScript:176
success line 2 > injectedScript:171
jQuery 6
doSensorIn2p5 line 2 > injectedScript:162
SetGraphView0 line 2 > injectedScript:276
onclick (index):1
```

Without the wind data it works fine.

```
var doSensorIn10 = function(){
  let ReferenceColours = ['#79bc6a', '#bbcf4c', '#eec20b', '#f29305', '#960018' ];
  let ReferenceConcentrations10 = [0,25,50,90,180];
  let t ={chart: { renderTo: 'chartcontainerIn10',type: 'spline',alignTicks: false, zoomType: 'xy', pinchType: 'xy'},
  title: { text: 'AirQuality Sensor In for PM10'},
  credits: { enabled: true},
  xAxis: { type: 'datetime', ordinal: false, dateTimeLabelFormats: { day: '%e %b',week: '%e %b %y',month: '%b %y',year: '%Y'} },
  yAxis:
    [{
      title: { text: 'Luchtkwaliteit (μg/m3)'},
      opposite: false, labels: { align: 'right',x: -5},
    },
    {
      linkedTo: 0,
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      opposite: true,
      title: { text: null},
      labels: { align: 'left',x: 5},
      tickInterval: 20
    }],
  legend: { enabled: true},
  tooltip: { valueSuffix: 'μg/m3',valueDecimals: 1,xDateFormat: '%A, %b %e, %H:%M'},
  series:[],
  rangeSelector:
  {
    buttons:[{ count: 6,type: 'hour',text: '6h'},
             { count: 12,type: 'hour',text: '12h'},
             { type: 'all',text: 'All'}],
    inputEnabled: false
  }
};
let chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(t);
chart.showLoading();

$.ajax({
  url: 'airlinkdataIn10.json', 
  cache: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(resp){
    let titles = {
'In_pm10': 'In_pm10','In_pm10_1hr': 'In_pm10_1hr','In_pm10_3hr': 'In_pm10_3hr','In_pm10_24hr': 'In_pm10_24hr','In_pm10_nowcast': 'In_pm10_nowcast','wind': 'wind'}
    let idxs = ['In_pm10','In_pm10_1hr','In_pm10_3hr','In_pm10_24hr','In_pm10_nowcast','wind']
    let cnt = 0;
    idxs.forEach(function(idx) {
      console.log('idx =  ' + idx);
      if (idx in resp) {
        if (idx == 'wind') {
          console.log('Doing Wind correctly : Before addSeries');
          chart.addSeries({name: titles[idx], type: 'windbarb', showInLegend: false, onSeries: 'InPM2p5', tooltip: {valueSuffix: ' m/s'}, data: resp[idx] }, false);
          console.log('Doing Wind correctly : After addSeries');
        }
        else {
          console.log('Doing ' + idx + ' correctly');
          chart.addSeries({name: titles[idx], data: resp[idx]}, false);
        }
        chart.series[cnt].options.zIndex = cnt+50;
      }
      cnt++;
    });
    chart.hideLoading();
    chart.redraw();
  }
}
)};
```

The data series (in short version) is as follows:

```
{"In_pm2p5":[[1609484460000,26.20], ... ]],
 "In_pm2p5_1hr":[[1609484460000,32.90], ... ]],
 ...
 "wind":[[1609484460000,0.0,194], ...]]}
```

Each parameter has 2880 values, wind may have one value less (which I tested in jsfiddle and does not seem to be a problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your wide and clear description!

1. In this case it is hard to say why the chart is not rendering properly without reproduction of your data fetching. The `addSeries` feature should work without any issues with the `windbarb` type series.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ktLyunw8/

2.

> in the jsfiddle the onSeries attribute does not work. What is wrong there?

I cannot see it, everything seems to work fine:
[image]

3.

> And finally: is it possible to get the windbarbs above the series graphs and not fixed on the x-axis?

Like in the case of using the [`onSeries` feature](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.windbarb.onSeries)? Or render it totally above the plot area?

---

> I'd like to render it above the plot area or in the top of the plot area (like without onSeries it is at the bottom) so all windbarbs in one line.

In this case, you can render the second `xAxis` and assign the winbarb series to it.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.opposite

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ud0kyrgh/

Comment: Thank you for your answer: 1) See my next comment. 2) the onSeries had been solved with the help of somebody else: I did not use 'id' but 'name' as reference. Solved in the fiddle you see. 3) I'd like to render it above the plot area or in the top of the plot area (like without onSeries it is at the bottom) so all windbarbs in one line.

Comment: 1) _"without reproduction of your data fetching."_  I could supply links to the actual code and the datafiles (or post them if that is possible) but that would make it a bit more complex to understand I guess. Let me know if you would appreciate the links.

Comment: 1. It will be great if you will try to reproduce your data fetching. You can copy a sample of your data defined as a `wind`, use some online JSON storage, like this https://jsonbin.io/ and create a sample demo, like this : https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h2jwmaco/

2. I see. 3. Check my answer edit

Comment: Thank you, the second x-axis has that solved OK. 
The reproduction of the data fetch may take some time, I never used the online JSON storage. I'll have to study this. When done and working I'll get back to you. Is that OK? Thank you so far!

Comment: OK, I did the JSON storage. I created a [new jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HansR/3t6k7odz/10/) with everything in it. It runs and creates an error. I understand the error but looking at the code I do not see it.

Comment: line 79: this zindex option makes that the error occurs. https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ybkr4Lde/  you should define the zIndex (if you need to control it) in the series config which is added to the chart (just like the `name` or other properties)

Comment: Yes. Got it. The cnt error showed up as if it occurred in the addSeries. This was an educational exercise! Thank you very much, more than highly appreciated.

Comment: OK, I was too fast. It did run with the small test set. But then I created the full dataset I want to use and then it really fails: _"Script error."_  (no other info). This time the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HansR/3t6k7odz/23/) contains the ref to the full dataset (2880*6 datasets of which the wind dataset holds three numbers, the other sets two) And again the stackdump with **r** undefined

Comment: @HansRottier it looks like a `turbothreshold` blocks it, take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q4n51emo/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.turboThreshold HOWEVER, take a look at your dev console, it seems that your data is not filtered in the ascending order.

Comment: Yes. It is working in the operational situation. Thanks!!  The ascending order I will check but that should be OK, only the wind series is lacking the last point. Not very important. I will check. Problem solved I guess (hope not cheering too soon ;)

Really very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @HansRottier you're welcome! :) Highcharts support team is always willing to help!